# 0 ValueError The _name attribute report.test_module.report_test_doc is not valid. [Qweb- Odoo]

Tags: python, report, odoo, qweb

I'm trying to use report parser, but it always pop an error

```
ValueError  The _name attribute report.test_module.report_test_doc is not valid
```

I searched that your report name is use for the parser _template and _name in order to be used by Odoo. It doesn't show the error if I remove the test_module, but the hello() is not callable.

**report.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data>
        <report 
            id="eport_monthly_pdc"
            string="Monthly report of PDC"
            model="account.voucher"
            report_type="qweb-pdf"
            name="test_module.report_test_doc" 
            file="test_module.report_test_doc" 
        />
    </data>
</openerp>
```

**report_parser.py**

```
from openerp import api, models
from openerp.report import report_sxw
import time
class report_parser(report_sxw.rml_parse):
    def __init__(self, cr, uid, name, context):
        super(report_parser, self).__init__(cr, uid, name, context=context)
        self.localcontext.update({     
            'time': time,            
            'hello_world': self._hello,
        })
    def _hello(self):
        return "Hello World!"

class report_parser_test(models.AbstractModel):
    _name = 'report.test_module.report_test_doc'
    _inherit = 'report.abstract_report'
    _template = 'test_module.report_test_doc'
    _wrapped_report_class = report_parser
```

**report_test_doc.xml**

```
<openerp>
<data> 
<template id="report_test_doc">
    <t t-call="report.html_container">
        <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="o">
            <t t-call="test_module.report_test_layout">
                <div class="page">
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <span t-esc="hello_world()"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </t>
        </t>
    </t>
</template>
</data>
</openerp>
```

Answer (score 2):

In Your case basically,

Qweb report is mainly used to call using `models.AbstractModel` model of your every class entry for each report type and inherit it in your class for parser class entry.

```
class report_parser_test(models.AbstractModel):
    _name = 'report.test_module.report_test_doc'
    _inherit = 'report.abstract_report'
    _template = 'test_module.report_test_doc'
    _wrapped_report_class = report_parser
```

**Attributes of Each Qweb Report parser class Entry :**

**_name** **attribute** which is always start with `report.<your report template id>`

**_inherit = 'report.abstract_report'**
It's default inheritance of report.abstract_report which is located in report module (Base class of Every Report)

**_template = 'test_module.report_test_doc'**

Which is basically `<your module name>.<your report template id>`

**_wrapped_report_class = report_parser**

Which is part of the entry of your parser class which is contain  your report logic and computed logic for your report.

**And another things about to call your hello() call :

In your case You function is declare and added your report parser class is good but we must need to call that function on Qweb Template file

likes..

```
<span t-esc="hello()"/>
```

Then and then you will calling that function from your end.

I hope my answer may helpful for you :)

Comment: ok no problem but finally welcome and nice efforts to solve by your self

Answer (score 0):

Module name (i.e directory) in UPPERCASE raise this error in Odoo11.
Example:

`_name = 'report.Name_Module.report_name'`

Comment: In my case, I had `report_name` in uppercase which raised this error. After keeping the name in lowercase, the issue was resolved. Thanks.